# How to improve performance of searching in text change Android

Tags: android, performance, for-loop, textwatcher

I have one textWatcher to detect text change in my search bar. Once a text change occur, it will immediately perform a search action.

For example, when I type "a" in search bar, it will run  `itemData.name.toLowerCase().contains("a");`in a for loop to search item that name include "a" and display it in recycle view

Then I continue type "b", it will run 
`itemData.name.toLowerCase().contains("ab");`in a for loop again to search item that name include "ab".

This is the idea

```
//this will run when text change occur
for(){//for all item of itemlist
    if(){//if item name contains the text 
        //store this item in itemlist
    }
}
//update new itemlist to recycle view here
```

However, the performance is very slow. It will have some lag when I type in search bar. Anyone have solution about this?

Comment: @AkshayKatariya it will still lag when the dateset is large because of the for loop

Comment: @pskink , not from sqlite db, load data from mysql ,around 1k data, so like 1 text change, a 1k for loop need to run

Answer (score 3):

During auto-complete, you expect the results to get filtered with every keystroke. In contrast, you want a search get triggered once you finished typing. In case the user didn’t finish typing his keywords, we’d execute a search request with every key typed.

To avoid that many requests and optimize search experience, you can use a `TextWatcher` for the search field `EditText`.

```
private EditText searchText;  
private TextView resultText;  
private Timer timer;

    private TextWatcher searchTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {  
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // user typed: start the timer
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // do your actual work here
                }
            }, 600); // 600ms delay before the timer executes the „run“ method from TimerTask
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // nothing to do here
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // user is typing: reset already started timer (if existing)
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    };
```

> This snippet just shows you the exemplary use case to solve the
>   problem on how to guess when the user finished typing and wants to
>   start the search without having a submit button. We use a delay of 600
>   milliseconds to start the search. If the user types another letter
>   into the search field, we reset the timer and wait another 600 ms.

Comment: I getting this error android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. when I put notifyDataSetChanged() to update recycle view inside run() of afterTextChanged()